# Decode a text which is encoded with UTF-8

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to decode a text which is encode with UTF-8.

My code is here :

```
StringDecode[X_] := ImportString[X, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
StringDecode["Applications num\\303\\251riques"]
```

It seems that it doesn't work.

The result I would like to obtain is "Applications numériques".

What should I modify in the use of `ImportString` ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have too many backslashes. `ImportString["\"Applications num\303\251riques\"", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]` does what you want.

If you already have the string imported into Mathematica incorrectly, you can use `FromCharacterCode` with `ImportString`, with its second option.

```
In[1]:= "Applications num\303\251riques"

Out[1]= "Applications numÃ©riques"

In[2] := ImportString[%1, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]

Out[2]= {65, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 115, \
 32, 110, 117, 109, 195, 169, 114, 105, 113, 117, 101, 115}

In[3]:= FromCharacterCode[%2, "UTF8"]

Out[3]= "Applications numériques"
```

To go directly from the quoted string `"Applications num\\303\\251riques"`, you can use the above approach together with `ToExpression`:

```
ToExpression["\"Applications num\\303\\251riques\""]
```

ouputs

```
"Applications numÃ©riques"
```

which you may then plug into the `FromCharacterCode @* ImportString` lines above. Always be careful with `ToExpression`, and don't use it unless you are sure that the input string doesn't encode some malignant Mathematica input. The undocumented `ToExpressionSecure` in package `Security` might be of assistance in that case, but I don't know anything about it other than that it exists and calls `InsecureExprQ` in the `Security` package.

That is, the function is:

```
removeBackslashes[str_] := ToExpression["\"" <> str <> "\""]
StringDecode[x_] := FromCharacterCode[ImportString[removeBackslashes@x, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"], "UTF8"]
```

Demonstration:

```
StringDecode["Applications num\\303\\251riques"]
"Applications numériques"
```

Comment: Hm... But the reason he has too many backslashes is becuase that is how mathematica encodes symbol \.  For instance `Characters["Applications num\\303\\251riques"]` would give '{"A", "p", "p", "l", "i", "c", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "s", " ","n", "u", "m", "\", "3", "0", "3", "\", "2", "5", "1", "r", "i", "q", "u", "e", "s"}', so actually he has only singular backslashes. I have not found an easy way to go from his example, to actually importing the string without manually removing backslashes?

Comment: Excellent after edit, upvoting!

Comment: @Patrick Stevens
Thanks a lot for your help.
Unfortunately, I haven't understand the end and for the moment, I only obtain the result : "Applications numÃ©riques"
1) Can you reformulate you explaination between In[3] and Out[3]? Because with this FromCharacterCode[%2, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"], i have an error and I didn't obtain yet the good result.
2) It should be linked how do you use directly FromCharacterCode @* ImportString ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? I'm on 10.2.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens I use this version of mathematica 10.0.2.0. I hope a solution will be also possible.

Comment: Could you confirm that the last few lines of my post above do not work (`removeBackslashes`, `StringDecode` and the Demonstration)? I might have edited it since you last saw it.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens Indeed, I haven't seen it before. However, it still doesn't work for me. I still obtain the result : Applications numÃ©riques. If you want (and tell me how), I can send you my .nb file. Thank you for your help and hope you will have new ideas to handle this problem.

Comment: @Bendesarts, the above should now work. I mistakenly used CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8" instead of just "UTF8" as the second argument to FromCharacterCode.

Comment: @PatrickStevens It works !!! Great ! Thank you for your help